# does adding a dummy parameter to constructors of a class to solve calling ambiguity, violate any rule?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, ambiguity, named-constructor

take following class and two object definitions:

```
class Rect{
 public:
  enum centimeter;
  enum meter;
  Rect(double len,double wid,enum centimeter){
   length=(len/100);
   width=(wid/100);
  }
  Rect(int len,int wid,enum meter){
   length=len;
   width=wid;
  }
  //rest of implementation
 private:
  double length;//in meters
  double width;//in meters
};
Rect obj1(10,5,Rect::centimeter());
Rect obj2(10,5,Rect::meter());
```

two previous constructors have dummy enum parameters to solve calling ambiguity caused in case these dummy parameters didn't exist. Now in spite of possibility of using named constructors here, if I insist on using these dummy parameters, does this violate any coding rule that I should be aware of ?

Comment: IMO, the cleaner approach is to define the entire interface of the class to be in one unit (i.e., meters for length) and require the user of the class to do the conversions himself.

Comment: Setting members in the constructor body (they should be initialized in the *ctor-initializer-list*) is a bigger problem than the extra parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STL uses that idiom to differentiate iterator types in lieu of concepts.

Comment: @David: I think MSN refers to those where common implementations _internally_ use default arguments like `std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category` in order to differentiate between iterator pairs and two `int` (as in `std::vector<int> v(0,0);`). However, I think a better example from the std lib would be `new(std::nothrow)`.

Answer (score 10):

I think it violates my taste. I would code it like this:

```
enum Unit {
  Centimeter = 100, 
  Meter      = 1
};

Rect(int len, int wid, Unit unit) {
  length = len / (int) unit;
  width = wid / (int) unit;
}

Rect obj1(10, 5, Rect::Centimeter);
Rect obj2(10, 5, Rect::Meter);
```

Comment: @litb: you make a good point. But when the extra param is a type, often a compile time decision can be made (since it is calling a separate constructor based on the params type). Of course this is nothing you don't already know ;) and in this case I prefer the method you suggest here since it is simply choosing units.

Answer (score 4):

[BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) could be the answer here.

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF( double, Meter )
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF( double, Centimeters)
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF( double, Furlongs)

class Rect
{
 public:
  Rect(Meter len, Meter wid) : length(len), width(wid) 
  {};

  Rect(Centimeter len, Centimeter wid) : length(len/100), width(wid/100) 
  {};
}

Rect obj1(Meter(10),Meter(5));
Rect obj1(Centimeter(10),Centimeter(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't say this breaks a rule, but... It isn't easy to read.

Why can't you declare a

```
enum metrics {
  centimeter,
  meter
};
```

and use it as the constructor parameter? Or it can be

```
class Rect {
public:
  static Rect CreateWithMeters(int width, int height);
  static Rect CreateWithCentimenets(int width, int height);
}
```

Either is better than current code at my taste.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rect(int len,int wid,enum centimeter){
  length=(len/100);
  width=(wid/100);
}
```

In addition to what others wrote, this logic is bad, because `Rect(99,99,Rect::centimeter())` is equal to `Rect(0,0,Rect::centimeter())`.

If you are storing meters internally, do not provide an interface with centimetres, not this way nor any other way.

Comment: I took care of it, shouldn't have taken integer as type of parameters of the constructor that has a parameter of centimeter enum type, changed it to double.

Comment: Doesn't particularly help, the fractional meters are still discarded.

Comment: You should change the private variables as well or it won't help much. Of course, then you should change the other constructor for consistency.

Comment: Well, 0-99cm _are_ 0m, that's just the way it is when you round to the nearest meter.

Comment: changed type of private variables to double, not to get numbers rounded.